# Extending deployments with default configuration

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a config map that defines some variables like environment that are then passed into alot of deployment configurations like this

```
- name: ENV
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: my-config-map
          key: ENV
```

secrets and some volumes like ssl certs are common across the configs also.  Is there some kubernetes type that I could create a base service deployment that extends a normal deployment? Or some other way to deal with this? Also using kustomize, there might be an option there.

Comment: It is possible through PodPreset, take a look at the details from the following link https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/#pod-spec-with-configmap-example

Comment: Ah very nice! Missed that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PodPreset object to inject information like secrets, volume mounts, and environment variables etc into pods at creation time.

Before starting using PodPreset you need to take few steps:

- Firstly need to enable API type `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpreset`, which can be done by including `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1=true` in the `--runtime-config` option for the API server
- Enable the admission controller PodPreset. You can do it by including PodPreset in the `--enable-admission-plugins` option value specified for the API server
- After that you need to creatie PodPreset objects in the namespace you will work in and create it by typing `kubectl apply -f preset.yaml`

Please refer to [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/) to see how it works.